# Installation of Ubuntu 13.04 desktop (i386)

Tags: system-installation, 13.04, 32-bit

I am trying to install "ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso" on a Dell optiplex gx270.

I used "Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.3.5" to get it on an external Seagate Freeagent USB harddrive.  No problem.  I attach to Seagate to the desired computer to install Ubuntu and it boots to the USB with no problem.

The screen hangs with the Ubuntu logo for a while, then I get the error message:

```
(initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

Please can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Either, create the live boot again on your hard drive, or use a usb stick. I've had problems on external hard drives before, so the best bet is a usb stick instead. Hope this helps.